# Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, delete-row

When I try to do this:

`var row = datagrid.CurrentRow;
 name.RemoveAt(row);`
(name is a list of strings)

This error appears "Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'int'"

I need to convert the row to int so I can delete it.

Comment: You can't convert a DataGridViewRow to an int.  The `RemoveAt` method takes an index of the list item to remove.  If you know what index your row resides at, you can remove it by passing that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGridViewRow` is not an integer but you can get the `Index` of the row:

```
name.RemoveAt(row.Index);
```

Comment: The OP stated that `name` is a collection of strings, and they're not necessarily in the order you're answer is suggesting.

Comment: @roryap they're not necessarily not either. I answered the question, I can't guess if OP is not sorting or populating appropriately.